# function add() with select, but i cant select the same number twice

Tags: javascript

I cant select the same number twice, I am trying to use select to input the number and use the function to add them together.

```js
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" > </script>

<script>
  const firstFunct = (() => {
    let counter = 0;
    return () => {
      counter += +document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
      document.getElementById("Group 1 score").innerHTML = counter;
      if ((counter) >= 54) {
        document.body.innerHTML = "<p class='Group'>Group 1 Win</p><p onClick='location.reload()'                 class='Again'>Again</p>";
      }
    };
  })(); 
</script>
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="mySelect" onchange="firstFunct()">
    <option value="" disabled selected style="display:none;">+</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>12</option>
    <option>14</option>
    <option>16</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="54">win</option>
  </select>
</form>
<p id="Group 1 score" style="font-size: 75px;">0</p>
```

Comment: Declare counter outside of your function (global scope) each time furstFunc gets called it resets counter to zero. And for good measure wrap the value hitting the JS in a parseInt (values come back from the HTML as strings)

Comment: Because `firstFunct()` is called as the onchange event triggers. If you are choosing the same option twice, the selected value doesn't change and hence `firstFunct()` is not called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the firstFunct, as given below. The added line of code clears the last selected value after it has been added to the counter. That allows you to select the same value repetitively.

```
<script>
      const firstFunct = (() => {
        let counter = 0;
        return () => {
          counter += +document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
          document.getElementById("mySelect").value = null; //**this would clear the last selected value 
          document.getElementById("Group 1 score").innerHTML = counter;
          if ((counter) >= 54) {
            document.body.innerHTML = "<p class='Group'>Group 1 Win</p><p onClick='location.reload()'                 class='Again'>Again</p>";
          }
        };
      })(); 
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `firstFunct()` function is only called on a change of the `select` element. According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) documentation of the `change` event, the event is only called when the value **changes**. So if you select the same value twice, the event won't fire. If you want the function to fire every time, you may consider to use the `input` event. You can find the documentation for this event [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input).

Comment: <input type="button" onclick="firstFunct()" value="+">